# Is it possible to pass parameters from MWE2 configuration to XTend

Tags: xtext, xpand

for very long time I used XPand with MWE2 and there is a variable mechanism that I can define in MWE2 and pass it to XPand Template, like the following.

```
component = org.eclipse.xpand2.Generator : javaGenerator {
   metaModel = umlMM
   globalVarDef = { name = "java_version" value="${java_version}"}

   outlet = {
      path="target/generated-sources"
   }
   expand = "template::Root::Root for model"
}
```

Now I am trying to convert this to XTend but I can find way to pass this information to generator....

Similar structure is available...

```
component = org.eclipse.xtext.generator.GeneratorComponent {
   register= setup
   slot = 'model'
   outlet = {
     path = "target/generated-sources"
   }
}
```

but I don't see any mechanism on

https://github.com/eclipse/xtext-core/blob/master/org.eclipse.xtext/src/org/eclipse/xtext/generator/GeneratorComponent.java

Is there way to do same thing with XTend?

Thx for answers

Comment: i am not aware of this. of course you could simply customize / subclass GeneratorComponent

Comment: Yeah, I think that is the only reasonable thing to do...